# Should I move raspbmc logs out of SD card?

Tags: raspbmc, sd-card

I've noticed that raspbmc stores logs on SD card, not in tmpfs. Digging deeper I've discovered  it was changed recently as the raspbmc changelog for [June update](http://www.raspbmc.com/2013/06/raspbmcs-jam-packed-june-jollifications/) says:

> /tmp and /var/log no longer stored in ZRAM tmpfs

I don't understand this decision. SD cards have limited number of write cycles so I would expect raspbmc to store logs out of it.

I am concerned about my SD card lifetime and would like to keep it live as long as possible. Should I move logs directory back to memory filesystem or to external location (I have a NAS server in my network)?

Comment: Just a note -- it is completely absurd to believe that what happens in `/var/log` could ever wear out your SD card.  You could leave it on 24/7 and the card will live longer than you if that's all it's doing.  Much longer -- see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84902/pimp-rsyslogd-to-have-less-i-o-cron-pam-and-less-logging for the general point *("logging is not significant enough to worry about")* and the math that proves it.  It just does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove `persistent-logs` from cmdline.txt, logs will be stored in a tmpfs again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Impressed with responsiveness of the raspbmc creator! But I still don't understand why you decided to store logs on SD card by default. I think most users don't need persistent logs and if they stay with the default settings their SD cards may quickly wear out.

Comment: Hi, it's because a small tmpfs will hinder package installation via apt.

Comment: @MikołajPastuszko : Most users do want persistent logging, even if they don't know it.  It *will not* wear your SD card out and very likely one day will save you a pile of headaches.